# Does SQL Replication Fragment Indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, database-replication

I have a SQL Server with replication. The database in question has indexes with an avg_fragment_size_in_pages of 60-90% according to dm_db_index_physical_stats.

I would assume the answer is yes, but I'm looking for some confirmation as to whether a replicated database's indexes would fragment faster than a non-fragmented database's indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. SQL Server doesn't in any way transfer index fragmentation to other subscriber databases. If you setup transactional replication for example, you can copy objects like clustered index, nonclustered index,filtered index to subscriber database/s but not the fragmentation.

Comment: Right, I know the indexes don't transfer, but I'm wondering if replication would cause the indexes to fragment faster. I haven't seen any articles on that.

Comment: it depends. if you are sending `update`, `delete` commands to subscriber you could experience fragmentation base on how much data movement. You need index maintenance on subscriber database too.